# DLP data scan from bigquery table showing start byte as null

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I have scanned a Bigquery table from Google DLP Console. The scan results are saved back into a big query table. DLP has identified sensitive information, but the start byte is shown as  null, can anyone help me understand why?

[image]

The source data looks as follows:

```
2,james@example.org  ,858-333-0333,333-33-3333,8
3,mallory@example.org,858-222-0222,222-22-2222,8
4,maria@example.org  ,858-444-0444,444-44-4444,1 

------------------------------
```

If I put the same data in Cloud storage bucket and then perform a scan using DLP, I get the start and end bytes for the sensitive data

Comment: You mean that you don't get the "null" column in your data output when analysing data stored in a bucket - right ? Can you post sanitised version of the file you have in the bucket ?

Comment: Yes @Wojtek_B, that is right. When analysing data stored in a bucket, the output looks good. It gives the start bytes as not null values.  Sure, here is the data that is stored in the storage bukcket:
`1,mallory@example.org,858-222-0222,222-22-2222,5
2,james@example.org  ,858-333-0333,333-33-3333,8
3,mallory@example.org,858-222-0222,222-22-2222,8
4,maria@example.org  ,858-444-0444,444-44-4444,1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly this looks like a bug.

I was able to reproduce your issue completely; I fallowed these steps:

- screated a source csv file:

```
1,mail1@test.com,858-333-0333,333-33-3333,8
2,epaweda-8101@yopmail.com,858-333-0334,333-33-3334,3
3,petersko@live.com,858-333-0335,333-33-3335,5
4,danneng@gmail.com,858-333-0336,333-33-3336,1
5,chance@icloud.com,858-333-0337,333-33-3337,4
```

- imported it to a BQ table - it looks like this:
  [image]
- DLP'ed it and got the same result with `null` column:
  [image]

**In my opinion this is a bug (certainly looks like it) so my recommendation would be to go to [Google's Issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) and report it here (with as much details as possible) and wait for an answer.**

Comment: Thank you so much for your analysis @Wojtek_B. This really helped me !

Comment: Thanks @Kuwali for the confirmation - an "accept" would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks folks, the product team is investigating. What's happening is that "0" is mapping to null "by accident" due to a proto to BQ schema conversion bug on our end. We'll address this.